# SqlDateTime overflow, but I want a NULL or MinValue

Tags: c#, datetime, sqldatetime

On this project, I am tracking when something is created, edited, and finally processed. I have three DateTime fields setup for this. The code below is for when I create the record.

```
newsArchive.CreateDateTime = DateTime.Now;
newsArchive.ModifyDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
newsArchive.SendDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
naRepository.Add(newsArchive);
naRepository.Save();
```

I am getting "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM." when I try to add it. I know I can't send a NULL. How would you handle this?

I am using Linq2SQL to process this.

Comment: When you say you know you can't send a null - do you mean you can't use newsArchive.SendDateTime = SqlDateTime.Null; or do you mean you can't use newsArchive.SendDateTime = null; ?  Your subject indicates NULL would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you send a null? AFAIK, Linq2SQL supports nullable value types; you just need the column in the DB to be nullable or L2S won't project the DAO with the nullable type.

You could use (DateTime)(SqlDateTime.MinValue) instead of DateTime.MinValue. This will use the minimum SQL-compatible datetime value, explicitly cast to DateTime.

Though both SqlDateTime and DateTime actually store time as a UInt64 "Ticks" value, the difference between the two types is that SQL Server uses a different epoch (value for zero) and a different resolution (what 1 "tick" represents in fractions of a second) than the CLR's DateTime.

Comment: Weird I thought that errored out before. It works now. I can use `= null` and have it work fine. The DateTime on server allows nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of SQL Server are you using? If you are using SQL 2008 (or 2008 R2) you can use the [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) data type which can support the full range of the .NET DateTime type.

Otherwise, use NULL (your model will need to have a property of type `Nullable<DateTime>`) or live within the limitations of the data type and DateTime.MinValue exceeds the limit of the SQL datetime type.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own minimum date - a Date variable with value 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM  and use that instead of DateTime.MinValue

Answer (score 0):

The datetime2 datatype allows dates as early as year 1. You can also use DateTime? to allow null dates in your .net code